# Chrome hangs on "sending request" appears to be socket related

Tags: sockets, google-chrome

When I load the url for a rather large application I'm working on, I'd say every 3-4th reload the application hangs and stops loading. Chrome reports "sending request" in the lower left. I can't seem to identify any file its stopping up on, but instead found this thread:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55046

which indicates it might be a socket issue. Flushing sockets from this page (chrome://net-internals/#sockets) instantly frees up the page and everything proceeds to load normally. Here's an image from that chrome internals page

[image: chrome internals socket page]

I realize that this may indeed be a chrome bug, but in the meantime, I need a workaround, since users are hitting this bug in chrome, and can't load the application. 
Ideas?

Comment: does this question need a larger bounty? Better description of the problem? I'm still stuck on this-

Comment: Make sure your server is providing the content-length header and EOF char '\0' at the end of the body. If that doesn't work, try changing your server's timeout period. It might also be something to do with the content expiry header. Good luck.

Comment: I don't use Chrom(ium) for this reason - I've regularly encountered this bug. I would like to note that if I watch the apache access logs on my site, when Chrome hangs on loading, Chrome seems to think it's sent the request, but it does not show in the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of 2 workarounds, none are exactly convenient though:

1. Disable SPDY: `"...\chrome.exe" --use-spdy=off` (unfortunately cannot be done via flags)
2. Disable Sync ("Settings - Disconnect your Google Account")

Another option is to reduce number of connections within your app (serve all static content from 1 domain + 1 websocket connection for all client-server communication), and remove widgets (twitter, disqus, etc which keep persistent connections) where possible, which may or may not help considering the socket pool is shared between all Chrome tabs :(

Personally for me this bug occurs to random websites since Chrome 21, and is somewhat countered by crashes which reset the pool :)

Comment: Urgh, well, reducing connections was the only thing I came up with as well, good to hear that's what someone else is doing too-

Comment: Ok, for anyone else coming to this post, I finally solved this by reducing the number of redirects being made by my application. We had a number of images that were being loaded from the same domain, but a different root context, and those redirects were piling up and apparently stalling the app

Comment: I don't have sync set up, bug still exhibits.

Answer (score 1):

After your suggestion about the images being redirecting and by using **Fiddler2** I saw that I also had a lot of redirects in images.
In my case, I have a rewrite rule in **ASP.NET MVC** that lowercases our URLs. This was also the case for our projects folders, in this case, the one that contains the images, e.g. `URL/Images/OurLogo.png` became `url/images/ourlogo.png`.

Changing our rewrite rule to include the following line in the conditions tag, solved the issue:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
```

Full rewrite rule for reference:

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="false" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```